# Tk/Tkinter Canvas "<ItemDelete>" event?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there an event fired when an item on a Canvas is deleted? I fear from looking at [the Canvas man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M29) that there's no such thing, but wanted to confirm.

(The reason I'm looking for something like this is that I have an `<Enter>`/`<Leave>` binding pair that gets out of sync if the item is deleted while the mouse is over the item. Ideally, I'd just get`<Leave>` to be triggered in such a case, but that doesn't seem to be happening.)

---

FWIW: `Tcl 8.5`, `Tk 8.5`, `Python 2.7.9`, `Windows 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Since you are writing the code that deletes objects, you can always generate your own virtual event.

```
def delete_something():
    ...
    canvas.event_generate("<<ItemDeleted>>")
```

You'll have to manage keeping track of which item was deleted.

All that being said, you can check for the existence of the item in your `<Leave>` binding or just catch and ignore errors.

Comment: Thanks. The code doing the deleting is out of my control, but I think I'm going to subclass `Canvas` and override the `delete` method to generate a virtual event as you suggested. Will post back with results